# how to write a python code to mask the input as * in the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input ABC123 Output ***123 
The first half of the characters in the word should contain only alphabetic in the upper case. The second half of the words should contain only digits
While displaying the output all alphabetic should be masked with *.

Comment: This is a really basic question. It gets during the first 60 minutes of any Pythons beginner course, and can probably be Googled within seconds. Why ask such a question at stack overflow? Did you try anything? Do you have any knowledge in Python, or another non trivial language?

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
import re

input_str = "ABC123"
print(re.sub("[A-Z]", "*", input_str))
```

Output

```
'***123'
```

The regex will replace all alphabetic chars with * in a giving string

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string module to do this.

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase

input = "ABC123"
output = "".join("*" if x in ascii_uppercase else x for x in input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a translation table:

```
maskUppercase = str.maketrans("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","*"*26)

string = "ABCD1234"
print(string.translate(maskUppercase)) 

****1234
```

you could also reform the string using join() after masking the letters in a list comprehension:

```
"".join([c,"*"][c.lower()!=c] for c in string)
```